# Running Script via Process - not able to find script

Tags: swift, process

I am trying to run a script from a Mac OS/X application using Swift 5, but when running the process, it is failing to find the script (and I am sure I am missing something obvious, but can't see what)

I have tried passing in just the script name, the full url to the script and also with task.currentDirectoryURL completed and not completed; but still fails to find the script

```
public func run() -> Bool {

    let task = Process()
    // scriptURL    URL         "file:///Users/phil/Documents/My%20Scripts/"
    // name         String      "myscript"
    task.executableURL = scriptURL.appendingPathComponent(name).appendingPathExtension("sh")
    task.currentDirectoryURL = scriptURL
    task.arguments = []
    let outputPipe = Pipe()
    let errorPipe = Pipe()

    task.standardOutput = outputPipe
    task.standardError = errorPipe

    do {
        try task.run()
        let outputData = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        print(String(decoding: outputData, as: UTF8.self))
        return true
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        let handle = errorPipe.fileHandleForReading
        let errorData = handle.readDataToEndOfFile()
        print(String(decoding: errorData, as: UTF8.self))
        return false
    }
}
```

When task.run() is called it is getting caught by the Catch and the NSError is returning "The file “myscript.sh” doesn’t exist.", but it does exist in the ScriptsURL folder.

Comment: Off the top of my head, shouldn't the shell script be executed via a shell? I've not found any concert example or reference, but they seem to be pointing that way

Comment: Hmm, don't know - anyone else know if I am approaching this wrong?